# Django Channels 2 implementing Multiplexer/Demultiplexer like Channels 1

Tags: django, django-channels

Unless I am missing something it seems there is not an out-of-the-box solution for multiplexing a single channel in Channels 2 like we had with Channels 1.

My understanding is with 3 consumers in Channels 1 served by a single multiplexer/channel there is nothing analogous to this in Channels 2.

First option is that I'd rather not touch the client code and mimic a multiplexer unless this seems wrong-headed.

Other option (I think from my initial readings in Channels 2) is I'd just have 3 endpoints as websocket URL routes and change the client code to use multiple websockets using those routes.

Are those both viable options?  Which makes the most sense?

Or maybe I am missing something obvious, if I have 50 routes I need 50 consumers, does that mean the client needs 50 websockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is currently no Demultiplexer for Channels 2 and the [issue](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/825) is still open. However, you can use a separate package linked in the issue called [channelsmultiplexer](https://github.com/hishnash/channelsmultiplexer). I have used it and it provides a minimal multiplexing/demultiplexing mechanism for channels 2 needed to get a project running. I've had to do a bit of modification and customization to the one I use though but you can still use the package as it is